# How can I pass my animation to several widgets in Flutter?

Tags: animation, dart, flutter

I have based my animation on this tutorial: https://proandroiddev.com/animations-in-flutter-6e02ee91a0b2. Now I want to apply it to several widgets in my widget tree but to do this, I need to pass my Animation Controller to other classes, so that I can call .forward(). I have created a constructor:

```
    final AnimationController controller;
  const SlideIn({Key key, this.controller}) : super(key: key);
```

but this gives me an error here:

```
  @override
 void initState() {
super.initState();

widget.controller =
    AnimationController(vsync: this, duration: Duration(seconds: 2));
```

The error is: "'controller' can't be used as a setter because it is final." So how can I pass my controller to other classes so that I can use my animation in several places in my widget tree?

EDIT: I have come to the conclusion that this is not the correct way to use one animation for several widgets. If it was, I would find more on the above issue. Could anyone please let me know how I can do this:

I have a class with an animation for some of my cards (which are built in various other classes). How can I use this same animation for different cards in my widget tree?

Comment: Remove the final keyword?

Comment: Thanks, this is what I get - error: Can't define a const constructor for a class with non-final fields.

Comment: Remove the `const` from the constructor.

Comment: Thanks, but final is required anyway...

Comment: You should try to create your own `AnimatedWidget` and use it anywhere you want. I was only trying to give you a quick fix.